# Asynchronous Swift issues

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I am a Javascript developer poking around in Swift and am having a hard time migrating an example Playground app I found (https://github.com/gregiOS/Playgrounds/tree/master/BLE.playground) to a CLI app.

```
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport

let tableViewController = TableViewController()
let dataSource = tableViewController.dataSource

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = tableViewController.view

let scanner = BluetoothScanner { scanner in
    scanner.startScanning { (peripheral) in
        print("Discovered peripheral: \(peripheral.tableViewData)")
    }
}
```

My desire, and what I tried is to just remove `import PlaygroundSupport` and the `dataSource`/`tableViewController` stuff and just have the peripherals printed out to stdout, however the program just exits immediately. I tried using a dispatch group, but that didn't seem to work either:

```
import Cocoa

let myGroup = DispatchGroup()

print("Scanning...")
myGroup.enter()

let scanner = BluetoothScanner { scanner in
  scanner.startScanning { (peripheral) in
    print("Discovered peripheral: \(peripheral.tableViewData)")
    myGroup.leave()
  }
}

myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
  print("Finished all requests.")
}
```

Also tried using `myGroup.wait()` but it just sat there doing nothing. I believe part of the problem is that the scan runs indefinitely, whereas I just need it to run for 2 seconds or so and stop.

Point is, I'm in over my head and need to create a PoC showing Bluetooth discovery. I would greatly appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run asynchronous stuff in a CLI you need a runloop

```
let runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()
print("Scanning...")

let scanner = BluetoothScanner { scanner in
  scanner.startScanning { (peripheral) in
    print("Discovered peripheral: \(peripheral.tableViewData)")
    CFRunLoopStop(runLoop)
  }
}

CFRunLoopRun()
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [vadian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53680016), you don't necessarily need a run loop unless your code uses constructs that require one (e.g. `Timer`).

You can also call [`dispatchMain`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452860-dispatchmain) at the end of your program to start the [Dispatch system](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch). `dispatchMain` never returns, so you need to call `exit(0)` or similar to exit the program at an appropriate place:

```
import Dispatch

let myGroup = DispatchGroup()

print("Scanning...")
myGroup.enter()

let scanner = BluetoothScanner { scanner in
  scanner.startScanning { (peripheral) in
    print("Discovered peripheral: \(peripheral.tableViewData)")
    myGroup.leave()
  }
}

myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
  print("Finished all requests.")
  exit(0)
}

dispatchMain()
```